# Copy and paste markdown text to correctly formatted text in a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: windows, markdown, powerpoint, copy-paste

I have the following text in Markdown format.

```
Hello, check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/).
Here is a list of things
- Eggs
- Tomatoes
- Ship
```

And I would like to copy and paste it in a PowerPoint presentation, such that the link and the unnumbered list are correctly formatted in the target PowerPoint style. Here would be the expected result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8oFY.png

However, by simply copy-pasting, I get something like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kktt.png

How to convert from Markdown to formatted text in PowerPoint?

Currently, I am using the following way to achieve this:

1. Convert the markdown file to `.docx` using pandoc.
2. Open the `docx` file in Word
3. Copy paste the content to Powerpoint.

This perfectly works, but it is tedious work. Is there any way I could automate this?

I would like for example to convert some text from markdown text to formatted text in the clipboard which I can paste somewhere I want in my PowerPoint presentation.

I tried to use the following one-liner in Powershell:

```
pandoc -i myfile.md -t docx -o - | Set-Clipboard
```

But when I paste into Powerpoint, I get a strange result looking like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWYGl.png

Thanks for ideas and help!

2023-11-01 EDIT:
I searched for solution using Powershell and Pandoc, and ended up with the following powershell script which almost works.

```
$tempfile = ".\deleteme.rtf"
Get-Clipboard | pandoc -t rtf -o $tempfile
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"|Out-Null
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject([Windows.Forms.DataObject]::new([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Rtf,(Get-Content -Raw $tempfile)))
Remove-Item $tempfile
```

Only when the copied markdown text is more than one line, it won't work as expected: it will only convert the first line. However the `tempfile` seems fine, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong with the `Get-Content` command or somewhere else at the same line.

Comment: This project of mine might interest you. It converts whole Markdown files to complete presentations.

https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx

Comment: >> "But when I paste into Powerpoint, I get a strange result looking like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWYGl.png"  FWIW that's because you're pasting the contents of the file into PPT as though it were a text string; it's not. A DOCX is a zip file. The PK you're seeing is always the first few bytes of any zip file.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @SteveRindsberg, I see, that makes sense now.

Comment: @MartinPacker it is an interesting project, but in my case, I only want to paste the text into an already existing PowerPoint. That said, the reason I am using markdown is because I use Obsidian, and your project would be a very interesting add to Obsidian I think! ;) https://obsidian.md/plugins?search=powerpoint

Comment: Your template presentation could be the one you want to add slides to - with md2pptx. But I'm not trying to push it onto. But thanks for the steer on Obsidian - which I've largely avoided (being a Drafts user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to my issue. The following command will convert markdown text in the clipboard to HTML formatted text and set the clipboard with it.

```
Get-Clipboard | pandoc -t html -o - | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
```

Then I can paste the HTML text in the clipboard to my PowerPoint presentation.

One caveat is that bullet symbols are not well rendered, but the overall wanted result is obtained. It also works for any multi-line text present in the clipboard.